# Find paypal account information via API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

After reading the PayPal API for quite some time, I fail to see how to obtain account / account holder information. For the Account for which I have the API Username / Passwort and Signature. This leads me to the following questions:

a) is it possible to obtain those information.
b) how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

So just to clarify, you are wanting to receiving the account information for the account to which you have the API credentials for?  What information are you wanting to retrieve and why?  Typically, the account you have credentials for would be your own, and you would just log into access it.  If you are wanting to retrieve information about transactions you could use the API's to do this.  However, the API's won't return what information you have listed on your account, such as credit card number, email address, and things like that.

The GetPalDetails API returns the PayPal ID for the account who's API credentials you are using along with the country code.

Comment: Yes. I'd like to get some meta information on the account for which I hold the API credentials. E.g. the account holders name. (Apparently this is provided via the GetBasicPersonalData -- but it's not clear if that is available without permission token on the live system as well)

I'd also like to know if it's a Premier or other type of account.

Basically given some credentials, I'd like to get some meta information to display that account (hence, account type and holder name would be sufficient -- accounts cannot have a custom name, can they?)

Comment: The only problem with this is that you would have to have the front end user go through the flow to get the information returned back to you from the API call.  Meaning that the account holder would need to walk through your flow, enter in their email address and pwd, and agree to share the information with your site which would be making the API call.

Comment: Let us assume for now that the user shares with my application his email and api credentials; while I have no idea of the data. The application runs local on the users computer. At this point I cloud obtain the users transactions and display them to him, but the account is pretty much an opaque object, and displaying the account enriched with the users name and the account type would be at lot better.

Comment: If the user has gone through the flow and agreed to share the details with you and your site, then you would be able to make the api call to get the details that are allowed to be returned with the GetBasicPersonalData.